# Another Dynamic Segments issue in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a nested assets resource on my character resource. I've read all over SO that I should be able to use `this.modelFor` to get the associated parent model, but when I use it, my result is undefined. Where am I going wrong?

models/character.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  assets: DS.hasMany('asset', { async: true }),
  ...
});
```

models/asset.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  character: DS.belongsTo('character', { async: true }),
  ...
});
```

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('characters', function () {
    this.route('show', { path: '/:character_id'} , function() {
      this.resource('assets', function() {

      });
    });
  });
  ...
});
```

routes/character/show.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('character', params.character_id);
  }
});
```

routes/assets/index.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('character').get('assets');
  }
});
```

templates/characters/show.hbs

```
<div class="row">
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  {{#link-to 'assets' this}}Assets{{/link-to}}
</div>
```

As the this.modelFor('character') returns undefined:

```
Error while processing route: assets.index Cannot read property 'get' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

My routes look as I'd expect, yielding me a /chararcters/:charater_id:/assets route:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the model of a route that has a model. In your route layout, only the characters.show route actually has a model. That is the route you should be trying to get the model from